# Name for REST endpoint that serves the single closest match to a search

Tags: rest, naming-conventions, naming, restful-url

My REST API serves items at `/items`, and items by exact name at `/items?name=:name`. An API consumer needs another endpoint that serves the single item with "most similar" name, instead of 404ing when there is no exact match. What is the best practice for naming this endpoint? These two alternatives seem most reasonable to me:

- `/items/closest-match?name=:name`
- `/items?name=:name&match=fuzzy`

The items are also available by exact numerical ID match at `/items/:id`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real right or wrong way of doing what you need here, but I would point out that the endpoint URL should be a noun that describes a resource, so I wouldn't go with the first option since I don't think `/items/closest-match` is representing a resource here.

I like the second alternative, where you're filtering the items by name and also specifying how "strict" the match needs to be.